# Nexus LDAP search in two Base DN

Tags: ldap, nexus

In a Nexus LDAP integration I have to search in two 'Base DN'. under the 'Search Base', the one for real users and the other for functional users.

I tried Base DN (|(ou=*a*)(ou=*b*)) but not with the expected results.

Is there a way to provide and or relation ship between tow base DN keys or as alternative the possibility to search in two LDAP configurations?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to perform a single search limited to the scope of 2 base DNs in LDAP: One search - one base DN.

However, if your 2 base DNs share a common parent, you may search within a parent and try to limit the result set based on the attributes.

E.g. you have got `ou=a,o=example`, `ou=b,o=example` and `ou=c,o=example`. Assuming that sub-entries of all those 3 bases contain corresponding attribute `ou` with the matching value (in LDAP this is not ensured!!!), you could search within a base `o=example` with a filter `(|(ou=a)(ou=b))`.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus Pro supports the definition of multiple LDAP connections for just this reason. You can query multiple search bases or even multiple servers by defining multiple connections.

If you are using Nexus OSS you will have to get your LDAP administrators to configure LDAP so that all desired user accounts are exposed via one search base.

Comment: That's what i have feared. Thanks for clarification, so I don't have to search for solution any more.